# Yii2 alias to parent model table when using relation via and comparison operators

Tags: activerecord, yii2, relation

I have Yii2 relations

Model Variants (simplified)

Variants hasOne Reference Sequence

```
public function getReferenceSequence()
{
    return $this->hasOne(ReferenceSequences::className(), ['id' => 'reference_sequence_id'])->alias('referenceSequence');
}
```

Variants hasMany Annotations via ReferenceSequence

I want to join Annotations based on the model property 'start' and 'end'(integer values) using comparison operators.

THIS DOESN'T WORK

```
public function getAnnotations()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Annotations::className(), ['chrom' => 'name'])
            ->via('referenceSequence')
            ->andOnCondition(['AND',['>=','tx_start',$this->start],['<=','tx_start',$this->end]])
            ->alias('annotations');
    }
```

I'm looking for the Annotations that have the same chromosome, but also fall within the start/end range for the Variants model.

Instead of trying to inject the model properties  $this->start and $this->end which for some reason only results in one pair of values being used, rather than each search result model joining on the properties of the $this object, I want to use an alias to the parent table.

The 'on' condition should be something like:

```
->andOnCondition(['AND',['>=','tx_start','VARIANTS_MODEL_ALIAS.start],['<=','tx_start',VARIANTS_MODEL_ALIAS.end]])
```

In Yii1 there was the magic "t" alias but this doesn't work any more.

Answer (score 0):

Conditions like `->andOnCondition(['AND',['>=','tx_start',$this->start],['<=','tx_start',$this->end]])` will work only with lazy loading, since `$this` will refer to current model which run this query. If you do `Variants::find()` query is run from empty model, so `start` and `end` will be always empty (or have default value).

If you want to make this relation working you may try something like this:

```
public static function find() {
    return parent::find()->alias('variants');
}

public function getAnnotations() {
    return $this->hasMany(Annotations::className(), ['chrom' => 'name'])
        ->via('referenceSequence')
        ->andOnCondition([
            'AND',
            ['>=', 'tx_start', new Expression('variants.start')],
            ['<=', 'tx_start', new Expression('variants.end')],
        ])
        ->alias('annotations');
}

public function getReferenceSequence() {
    return $this->hasOne(ReferenceSequences::className(), ['id' => 'reference_sequence_id'])
        ->alias('referenceSequence');
}
```

This may work for joins (like `Variant::find()->joinWith('annotations')->all()`, but you will not be able to use this relation for lazy loading, and most likely you will not be able even to fetch annotations using this relation. This case is tricky, you may need to use trick from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51773166/5812455) or change your DB schema to simplify the whole problem.

Comment: That works on the main query, (allows me to use the T alias which i've set in the search query) but fails on the separate query that is generated to get all the annotation records.  In Yii1 we had Criteria->together but is there no equivalent in Yii2 to make it fetch those records together with the main query?  The main table alias isn't present in the 2nd fetch query.